# Using Navigator in Vaadin's ErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm creating a web application using SpringBoot (1.5.6.RELEASE) and Vaadin (8.1.4).

I have a Vaadin View which's `enter` method I annotated like this:

```
@SpringView(name = UserListViewVaadinInit.VIEW_NAME, ui = { WebUI.class })
public class UserListViewVaadinInit extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    [...]

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_admin')")
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // trigger the presenter to fill the view with data
        eventBus.publish(this, new ViewEnteredEvent(event));
    }
}
```

This part works fine: When a user without the `ROLE_admin` authority tries to access the view an `AccessDeniedException` is thrown.

When the exception is thrown, I want the user to be redirected to the `HomeView` (I will add a proper `AccessDeniedView` later). So I tried the following:

```
@SpringUI(path = WebUI.PATH)
public class WebUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setErrorHandler(event -> {
            if (event.getThrowable() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                getNavigator().navigateTo(HomeView.VIEW_NAME);
            }
        });
        // do some other initialization stuff
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

The `ErrorHandler` gets triggered correctly however the `navigateTo` throws an Exception (only the relevant part):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class did not have a SpringView annotation or an alias for it
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider.isViewValidForCurrentUI(SpringViewProvider.java:363) ~[vaadin-spring-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>       at com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider.getAllViewsForCurrentUI(SpringViewProvider.java:231) ~[vaadin-spring-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>       at com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider.getAllowedViewsForCurrentUI(SpringViewProvider.java:250) ~[vaadin-spring-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>       at com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider.getViewName(SpringViewProvider.java:307) ~[vaadin-spring-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>       at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.getViewProvider(Navigator.java:1145) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:534) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at de.teamsped.webapp.ui.WebUI.lambda$init$a1d28b15$1(WebUI.java:57) ~[main/:na]

Let's take a look at `isViewValidForCurrentUI`:

```
protected boolean isViewValidForCurrentUI(ViewInfo viewInfo) {
    String beanName = viewInfo.getBeanName();
    try {
        final Class<?> type = getWebApplicationContext().getType(beanName);

        Assert.isAssignable(View.class, type,
                "bean did not implement View interface");

        final UI currentUI = UI.getCurrent();
        final SpringView annotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(type, SpringView.class);

        Assert.notNull(annotation,
                "class did not have a SpringView annotation or an alias for it");
    [...]
}
```

I investigated and it seems that `getWebApplicationContext().getType(beanName);` (with `beanName` being `userListViewVaadinInit`) returns a proxy object which does not have the necessary `SpringView` annotation.

Any idea why that is and how to fix it?

**EDIT**
HomeView:

```
@ViewScope
@SpringView(name = HomeView.VIEW_NAME, ui={WebUI.class})
public class HomeView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "home";

    Label label = new Label("Home");


    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        this.addComponent(label);

    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // the view is constructed in the init() method()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `HomeView` implementation look like?

Comment: @Morfic Pretty boring, added the code

Comment: Except the `@ViewScope` which you can remove because it's added by `@SpringView` (unless you replace it with `@UIScope` case in which be aware that [annotation order is important](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/#_views_and_scopes)) everything else seems fine. It might be one of _those weird problems_... Would you be able to provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) for an in-depth investigation?

Comment: Good point about the annotation. I found a workaround and can unfortunately not justify to put much more effort into this. Maybe I'll come back to this in a few weeks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Please do share your temporary workaround if you have the time as I'm rather curious. If it were a proxy problem as you think, then I'd expect none of the views to work, and yet... So that really makes me wonder.

Comment: The workaround is just to not use the @PreAuthorize annotations at all and  instead get the currently active authorities from the SecurityContext and then just check them manually.